# Set vertical text correctly on table header cells

Tags: css, vertical-text

I'm not sure how do deal with this anymore - please see screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

the table header cell has one style - height: 166px;

then each table cell header contains a span with this style properties

```
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0 .5em;
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
transform: rotate(-90deg);
display: block;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: uppercase;
```

I also execute this JS code to make them tight:

```
$("table th span").each ->
  header_height = $(this).outerWidth()  if $(this).outerWidth() > header_height
  $(this).width $(this).height()
  return

$("table th").height header_height
```

These were my last attempt. Ideally there should be no empty space, if 2 words can fit in one line then they should and everything is centered/aligned.

Comment: Put this in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) and put all the CSS and HTML needed to re-create this in your question as well. Much easier to fix when we have all the pieces!

Comment: Please include some HTML, context is always helpfull. Are you sure you need `span` and `th`, would not `th` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have re-created this for you. Next time please include all the relevant HTML and CSS.

To get this to work:

- Set the right `min-width` on the `th` to stop the headers from overlapping each other. It needs to be just large enough to contain the longest string of text that you will have in the headers.
- Set the right `max-width` on the `span` to contain it inside the `th`. It should match the height of the `th` minus any padding.
- You could change the `min-width` to be smaller on headers that contain less text, if you wanted, by attaching a class to the smaller headers and specifying a smaller `min-width` for them.

There doesn't seem to be any need to use javascript / jQuery.

[Have an example!](http://jsbin.com/cufoq/4/edit)

[image: Screenshot]

CSS

```
th { 
    background: red; 
    height: 166px;
    min-width: 90px; 
    /* 
      min-width is large enough to stop 
      the longest header text you will have from 
      overlapping when the table is the smallest it will be 
    */
}

th span {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    max-width: 156px;
    color: #FFF;
    /*
      max-width contains the span and 
      must match the height of the th minus 
      any padding you want 
    */
}

.shorty {
    min-width: 70px;
}

/* 
   You could give a class like this
   to your shorter headers if you wanted 
   maybe apply it with javascript or
   if you use PHP / whatever you could
   apply it to strings of a certain size.
*/
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th><span>This is my really long text</span></th>
        <th class="shorty"><span>Shorty!</span></th>
        <th><span>This is my really long text</span></th>
        <th><span>This is my really long text</span></th>
        <th><span>This is my really long text</span></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: genius! just a few more if you can still help out - i edited your jsbin: http://jsbin.com/wonoxuvikini/1/edit. Clearly the first cell can show all the text within the cell, by making some of the words share in one line. i cannot expand the cell width anymore as its already wide enough. 2. this is user entered text, so it can have arbitrary length, I tried using overflow: hidden, text-overflow:ellipsis, however both top and bottom part of the text gets  cut off. Need only the last part of the text that gets cut off...